# How can i check user input in db and close connection then echo the input on the next page

Tags: php, sql

I have input form in test1.php and I want to check user input in database, if the user input does not exist in database, it proceeds to test2.php and echo the user input in test2.php. else, redirects back to test1.php and echo, not available.

Now, I am able to redirect back to the previous page if the input exist in sql but I am not able to echo the user input in test2.php after closing connection.

**Here is test1.php**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
    echo '<ul class="err">';
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
        echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="test-exec.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th>Email </th>
<td><input name="box" type="text" class="textfield" id="box" /></td>
</tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Check" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Here is test-exec.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('db/config.php');

$errmsg_arr = array();

$errflag = false;

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if(!$con) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

$box = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['box']);

if($box != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE box='$box'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Box already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: test1.php");
    exit();
}else {
    header("location: test2.php");
    exit();

mysqli_close($con);

}
?>
```

**And here is test2.php**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th>Email </th>
<td><input name="box" type="text" class="textfield" id="box" value="<?php echo $_POST['box']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You just want to redirect to another php page? Maybe this wis what can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @Rogier, they are 2 html, 1 php. one of the html submits form to the php and the php executes the input and echo the input on the next page.

Comment: I have been able to do it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question that way if someone else comes across the same problem, you will be helping them.

Comment: @Missy, okay, i will do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: test1.php");
    exit();
}else {
    $_SESSION['SESS_box'] = $box;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: test2.php");
    exit();

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>


then in the html use this:
<?php echo $_SESSION["SESS_box"]; ?> 
to echo the input.
```